# How can I calculate the logfold change between two different matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, biopython

I have a matrix with a biological network containing genes and their interactions.
From that I created another matrix and I excluded specific genes hence  interactions.
My two excel files *do not* have the same size, as I have deleted rows and columns from the second one.

I need to calculate the logfold change per column pairwise, meaning I need to somehow match the matrices accordingly so I can get the correct values. E.g Normal matrix:

| Node | ACKR2 | ACKR3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GNAI2 | 0.67 | 0.59 |
| GNAQ | 0 | 0 |

Ecluded matrix:

| Node | ACKR2 | ACKR3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GNAI2 | 0 | 0 |
| GNAQ | 0 | 0 |

So to calculate the logfold change I need to calculate log2(excluded-value)/(normal-value)
To avoid having division by zero, when there is one I need to set the result to 1 so the log(1)=0.
Also, whenever the operator or the denominator is 0, I find the next min value from the respective file, I multiply it with a small value so this way I will avaoid having inf values.

Based on this dummy values on the output I do not calculate it correctly. Either, the matching is not correct or soemthing else. What am i missing here?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    np.seterr(divide='ignore')
    
    # input and output file locations
    in_loc = r"C:\Users\..\Downloads"
    out_loc = r"C:\Users\..\Downloads"
    
    # read input files as dataframes
    df_normal = pd.read_excel(in_loc + r"\example-normal.xlsx")
    df_excluded = pd.read_excel(in_loc + r"\example-excluded.xlsx")
    
    # set Node as index for correct calculation
    df_normal = df_normal.set_index("Node")
    df_excluded = df_excluded.set_index("Node")
    
    # find common indices between the two dataframes
    common_indices = df_normal.index.intersection(df_excluded.index)
    
    # subset dataframes with common indices
    df_normal_matched = df_normal.loc[common_indices]
    df_excluded_matched = df_excluded.loc[common_indices]
    
    # replace denominator values that are 0 with the next smallest non-zero value
    min_normal = df_normal_matched[df_normal_matched > 0].min().min()
    if min_normal == 0:
        epsilon = df_normal_matched[df_normal_matched > 0].min().min() * 0.99
        df_normal_matched[df_normal_matched == 0] = epsilon
        min_normal = epsilon
    
    # replace numerator values that are 0 with the next smallest non-zero value
    min_excluded = df_excluded_matched[df_excluded_matched > 0].min().min()
    if min_excluded == 0:
        epsilon = df_excluded_matched[df_excluded_matched > 0].min().min() * 0.99
        df_excluded_matched[df_excluded_matched == 0] = epsilon
        min_excluded = epsilon
    
    # divide excluded by normal for the logfold change
    res = df_excluded_matched / df_normal_matched
    res[res == np.inf] = 1
    res[res == -np.inf] = 1
    
    # take the log2 of valid values
    res = np.log2(res)
    
    # save the new result to a file
    res.to_excel(out_loc + r"\example-logfold.xlsx", index=True)
```

So to calculate the logfold change I need to calculate log2(excluded-value)/(normal-value)
To avoid having division by zero, when there is one I need to set the result to 1 so the log(1)=0.
Also, whenever the operator or the denominator is 0, I find the next min value from the respective file, I multiply it with a small value so this way I will avaoid having inf values.

Based on this dummy values on the output I do not calculate it correctly. Either, the matching is not correct or soemthing else. What am i missing here?

Comment: You can find the example files here:

[df_normal][1]

[df_excluded][2]

[Results][3]


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QKaoQtEpdJwl5f2k-Kokr7EJjAZG2rMp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109609670631513431293&rtpof=true&sd=true
  [2]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hQa0zC1_b585CaodRuq_ZPYQdVbgZHVi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109609670631513431293&rtpof=true&sd=true
  [3]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aeTuftReOpwS4NM-qj6yMxig0V0W9cy8/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109609670631513431293&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: I'm clearly not asking for a debugging service...

Comment: Based on your statement "Based on this dummy values on the output I do not calculate it correctly. Either, the matching is not correct or something else. What am i missing here?"  what do you think you are asking for if not someone to debug your code?

Comment: To help me see where I have gone wrong in this. I'm not asking for the code to be debugged, I'm asking how to go about solving my specific problem. If you look into the issue I have you can see it isn't a simple case of debugging. Thank you for the links anyway though.